# How prove the greatest post-fixed point of monotonic function is a fixed point of function?

Tags: order-theory, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I have monotonic function  $f : \mathcal{P}(M) → \mathcal{P}(M)$ on $(\mathcal{P}(M),\subseteq)$

Is it possible to prove that greatest post-fixed point of  $f$ is a fixed point of $f$ not using Knaster/Tarski's theorem? If yes, could anyone please provide a full explanation to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Edited: M is a set and CCPO $(\mathcal{P}(M),\subseteq)$

Comment: What is a "post-fixed point"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich According to Davey & Priestley, Introduction to lattices and order, a *pre-fixpoint* $x$ is one satisfying $f(x)\leq x$ and a *post-fixpoint* is one satisfying $x\leq f(x)$. Of course the OP should have provided that information...

Comment: If $x \le f(x)$, then $f(x) \le f(f(x))$, so...

Comment: I can't check the details right now (such as does it use Knaster-Tarski), but that seems to be the order-dual of the result in 8.20 (page 186) of *Introduction to lattices and order* by Davey & Priestley.

Comment: I think $f$ may have no fixed point, without some assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know this notion but I [found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) that a postfixpoint of $f$ is any $P$ such that $f(P)\subseteq P$.

Let $M$ be a set and let $Q$ be its proper subset. Consider $f\colon \mathcal{P}(M)\to \mathcal{P}(M)$ defined by $f(A)=A\cap Q$. Then each set is a postfixpoint but $f(M)=Q\neq M$. The hpothesis is false.